# scala's Try elegant on error behavior

Tags: scala, refactoring, try-catch

Is there a more elegant way of doing this in scala?

```
def doTheDangerousThing(): Try[Result] = {
  val result = Try(dangerousOp)

  if (result.isFailure) {
     println("error")
  }

  result
}
```

Answer (score 19):

I think your if statement is perfectly valid. Here is another alternative:

```
def doTheDangerousThing(): Try[Result] = Try(dangerousOp) recoverWith {
    case exception => println("error"); Failure(exception)
}
```

Comment: Though valid (mine, that is), it looks a bit imperative. It would be nice to have a variant of `recoverWith` just for side-effecting, and not having to return `Failure` again.

Comment: @PabloFernandez agreed. I guess a `foreach` method designed for `Failure` could be useful. You can write your own with implicit conversion.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
   def doTheDangerousThing[Result](dangerousOp: =>Result): Try[Result] = Try(dangerousOp) match {
    case o @ Failure(_) =>  println("error"); o
    case _ => _
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

My preferred,

```
def doTheDangerousThing(): Option[Result] = Try (dangerousOp) toOption
```

If the `Try` is successful you will get a `Some(value)`, if it fails a `None`.

For a large compilation on `Try` uses, have a look at [Try introduced in Scala 2.10.0](https://gist.github.com/helena/4434689) .

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is more idiomatic, but sometimes I find that placing the `recoverWith` in this manner improves readability for me:

```
def doDangerousThing(): Try[Result] = Try {
  dangerousOp
} recoverWith {
  case t: Throwable => println("error"); Failure(t)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I suppose you could do something like this:

```
def doTheDangerousThing(): Option[Result] = 
  Try(dangerousOp) match {
    case Success(result) => Some(result)
    case Failure(e) => None //might want to log the error as well
  }
```

Comment: How is this code a replacement for the snippet in the question? What's the point of changing the return type? I think Pablo was just interested in replacing the if statement.

Comment: There is already `toOption` method in `Try`. And yes, it's not an answer.

Comment: This changes the return type and loses the `Exception`

Comment: This is how I would do this.  Deal with the exception here, instead of passing the Try up.  I hinted at this in the solution... add some code to log and/or deal with the exception in the case Failure(e) -- in which case it's superior to just using toOption.

Comment: I'll also add, I changed the return type because I'm dubious on the merit of examining the value within the Try in one place, and then returning the Try.. presumably so that it will be examined again somewhere else.  Are you going to have exception-handling code in two places?

Comment: Huh, looking at my own answer nearly 3 years later, I have to admit this doesn't make much sense to me.  What was I thinking? :D

Answer (score 2):

There are ways. For instance:

```
def doTheDangerousThing(): Try[Result] = {
  val result = Try(dangerousOp)

  result.failed foreach { _ =>
     println("error")
  }

  result
}
```

Or, if you don't want to repeat `result` all through, then:

```
def doTheDangerousThing(): Try[Result] = {
  Try(dangerousOp) recover {
    case ex => println("error"); throw ex
  }
}
```

Comment: @santiagomaldonado So? I'm calling `foreach` on that. It should ignore any `Failure` results, and work on any `Success` results, which seems to be exactly what I wanted (back 4 years ago, so please understand I have no recollection of this :)).

Answer (score 1):

In some cases I love to use two-step approach which will allow me a more granular error message control:

```
  def retrieveData(dataId: String): Try[String] = {
    Try {
      Option(someApi(dataId))
        .getOrElse(throw SomeApiFailedException("invalid dataId"))
    } recoverWith {
      case e: SomeApiFailedException => Failure(e)
      case e: Throwable => Failure(SomeApiFailedException("failed retrieve dataId"))
    }
  }

  case class SomeApiFailedException(err: String) extends RuntimeException(err)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could choose from either of the three implementations, depending on whether I want to:

- Simply propagate it upwards  ( `doTheDangerousThing1` )
- Ignore the error  ( `doTheDangerousThing2` )
- Intercept the error while propagating it upwards ( `doTheDangerousThing3` )

Here is the code:

```
import scala.util.{Try,Success,Failure}
object temp {
  type Result = Int

  def dangerousOp = {
    val r = scala.util.Random.nextInt(10)
    if (r > 5) r else throw new RuntimeException("Failed on " + r)
  }
  def logMessage[T](t: T) = println(t)

  def doTheDangerousThing1(): Try[Result] = Try(dangerousOp)

  def doTheDangerousThing2(): Option[Result] = {
    Try(dangerousOp) match {
      case Success(r) => Option(r)
      case _ => None
    }
  }


  def doTheDangerousThing3(): Try[Result] = {
    Try(dangerousOp) match {
      case t @ Success(r) => t
      case t @ _ => logMessage("failed: "+t); t
    }
  }
}
```

Inside the REPL

```
scala> doTheDangerousThing1
res0: scala.util.Try[Result] = Success(9)

scala> doTheDangerousThing1
res1: scala.util.Try[Result] = Success(9)

scala> doTheDangerousThing2
res2: Option[Result] = None

scala> doTheDangerousThing2
res3: Option[Result] = Some(7)

scala> doTheDangerousThing3
failed: Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed on 0)
res4: scala.util.Try[Result] = Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed on 0)

scala> doTheDangerousThing3
failed: Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed on 0)
res5: scala.util.Try[Result] = Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed on 0)
```